# How can I add a listbox in flex 4.6?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

Is there a list box in Flex 4.6?

If yes,can sm1 tel me how to implement a list box in Flex code

Thanks

Comment: Google: `flex 4.6 list`. The first result explains it, with examples.

Answer (score 2):

Flex has a [Spark List](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html) control, using an [`IList`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/IList.html) ([`ArrayList`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayList.html) or [`ArrayCollection`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html)) as the data provider.

[image: list]

**Declarative approach:**

Using MXML, this is implemented as `<s:List>`, as in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <s:List>
        <s:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <fx:String>Item 1</fx:String>
                <fx:String>Item 2</fx:String>
                <fx:String>Item 3</fx:String>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:dataProvider>
    </s:List>

</s:Application>
```

**Programmatic approach:**

From code, a list is instantiated and added to the display list such as:

```
import mx.collections.ArrayList;
import spark.components.List;

var list:List = new List();
list.dataProvider = new ArrayList([ "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" ]);
addElement(list);
```

**References:**

- [Spark List Control](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc2368ca491e3ff923c946c5112135c8ee9e-7fff.html)
- [Spark List API Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html)

Comment: @Swetha If you want a static factory class `static function addListBox():List { return new List(); }`.  Then, add the `VisualElement` using `addElement()`.

Comment: I need a method for listbox like private static function addListBox(parentGrp:BorderContainer, listBoxClass:XdListBox_XdBehavior_Select,tagAtts:Object):List{ }